# IOS-Charts set maximum visible x axis values

Tags: swift, charts, ios-charts

I'm using ios-charts (https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts). I have a LineChartView with 12 values in the x axis.
This however is far too many to see at the same time, so I want to display only 5 and then let the user drag to the right to see the next.

[image]

I've tried this:

```
    let chart = LineChartView()
    chart.dragEnabled = true
    chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(5)

    let xAxis = chart.xAxis
    xAxis.axisMinValue = 0
    xAxis.axisMaxValue = 5.0
    xAxis.setLabelsToSkip(0)
```

But still see all 11 values at the time. How can I only see 5?

Comment: same issue here, but reverse, I want to show all the values of xAxis (I have 12 values but it shows only 6 of them!! ) did you find any solution for your problem ??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I finally got it!

The correct answer is:

```
chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(5)
```

This however needs to be set **after** the data has been set in the chart (not in a configure before)

This did the trick for me

Comment: "needs to be set after the data has been set" is to be noted. thanks

Comment: this helped me but brought another problem. As my x axis values are TimeInterval of each day in the month, all the x axis values are same, scrolling indefinitely. how can I fix this? for example, if first x point is 10/10/16 in dd/MM/yy format all the other values also is same even after unlimited scrolling. whats wrong in this?

Answer (score 8):

You should set the X axis's labelCount property of the chart view.
In objc,like this

```
_chartView.xAxis.labelCount = 5;
```

**Swift**

```
chartView.xAxis.labelCount = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my finding!!

1. you don't need to really use label count
   if you are using DefaultAxisValueFormatter, NEVER use this. a lot of errors pop ! just use no2.
2. chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(number) will do.
   please put this **after chart data setting** [here](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/2460) you can see detail

   ```
   combinedChartView.data = combineData. //this need to come first
   combinedChartView.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(2) //after data setting
   ```

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote as an answer 4 years ago :)