# How to set maxVisibleCount variable in iOS charts

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I'm using Horizontal bar chart and all the values I have is between 10 and 30. 
I want to display the values in the chart, however the drawValuesEnabled depends on maxVisibleCount (from iOS-charts source)

From BaseDataSet.swift

```
/// Set this to true to draw y-values on the chart.
///
/// - note: For bar and line charts: if `maxVisibleCount` is reached, no values will be drawn even if this is enabled.
open var drawValuesEnabled = true
```

I see maxVisibleCount is set as 100 by default in BarLineChartViewBase.swift.

I tried to set maxVisibleCount to 5 in BarLineChartViewBase.swift.

This does not update the graph.

I use Pods to use iOS charts in my project.

Chart Settings:

```
    chartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = true
    chartDataSet.drawIconsEnabled = true
    chartDataSet.visible = true
    chartDataSet.colors = barColors


    let data = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .none
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
    formatter.multiplier = 1.0
    data.setValueFormatter(DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: formatter))
    data.setDrawValues(true)


    let xaxis = hBarChart.xAxis
    xaxis.labelCount = 24
    xaxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:hours)
    xaxis.granularity = 1
    xaxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    xaxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    xaxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    xaxis.labelTextColor = .darkGray

    let gridColor = UIColor(red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9, alpha: 0.8)
    let yaxis = hBarChart.leftAxis
    yaxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
    yaxis.gridColor = gridColor
    yaxis.enabled = true
    yaxis.labelPosition = .insideChart
    yaxis.labelTextColor = .darkGray
    hBarChart.rightAxis.enabled = true
    hBarChart.rightAxis.gridColor = gridColor
    hBarChart.backgroundColor = .white
    hBarChart.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    hBarChart.setVisibleYRangeMaximum(5, axis: .left)
    hBarChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(5)
    hBarChart.drawMarkers = true
    hBarChart.extraTopOffset = 20
    hBarChart.extraBottomOffset = 20
    hBarChart.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    hBarChart.drawValueAboveBarEnabled = true
    hBarChart.chartDescription?.text = "SDN Trend"
    hBarChart.animate(yAxisDuration: 1, easingOption: .easeOutBounce)
    hBarChart.legend.enabled = false
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576113/ios-charts-set-maximum-visible-x-axis-values - did you try this out

Comment: Yes. I tried it and did not work for me. I'll add my code for reference.

Comment: where do you set the data for the chart? because the setVisibleYRangeMaximum has to be done after the data has been set and not before that.